# Unity - C# - quick sort alghoritm - courutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quicksort

I am writing an app in Unity that will sort cubes by it's height. I'm stuck with Quick sort alghoritm.

Code is working correctly until the last 2 lines which are courutines instead of regular methods. Unfortunately they both run in paralel which is wrong... I'm looking for a way to build my code to run only one courutine at the time.

```
IEnumerator QuickSort(GameObject[] unsortedList, int left, int right)
{
    if (left < right)
    {
        GameObject temp;
        Vector3 tempPosition;
        float pivotValue = unsortedList[right].transform.localScale.y;
        int i = left - 1;

        for (int j = left; j < right; j++)
        {
            if (unsortedList[j].transform.localScale.y < pivotValue)
            {
                i++;

                temp = unsortedList[i];
                unsortedList[i] = unsortedList[j];
                unsortedList[j] = temp;
                if (i != j)
                {
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

                    tempPosition = unsortedList[i].transform.localPosition;

                    LeanTween.moveLocalX(unsortedList[i], unsortedList[j].transform.localPosition.x, 1f);
                    LeanTween.moveLocalZ(unsortedList[i], -3f, 0.5f).setLoopPingPong(1);

                    LeanTween.moveLocalX(unsortedList[j], tempPosition.x, 1f);
                    LeanTween.moveLocalZ(unsortedList[j], 3f, 0.5f).setLoopPingPong(1);
                }
            }
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

        temp = unsortedList[i + 1];
        unsortedList[i + 1] = unsortedList[right];
        unsortedList[right] = temp;

        tempPosition = unsortedList[i + 1].transform.localPosition;

        LeanTween.moveLocalX(unsortedList[i + 1], unsortedList[right].transform.localPosition.x, 1f);
        LeanTween.moveLocalZ(unsortedList[i + 1], -3f, 0.5f).setLoopPingPong(1);

        LeanTween.moveLocalX(unsortedList[right], tempPosition.x, 1f);
        LeanTween.moveLocalZ(unsortedList[right], 3f, 0.5f).setLoopPingPong(1);

        int pivotIndex = i + 1;

        StartCoroutine(QuickSort(cubes, 0, pivotIndex - 1));
        StartCoroutine(QuickSort(cubes, pivotIndex + 1, cubes.Length - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any reason not to use [Array.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-5.0)? If you do, it would be useful to include that reason in the question.

Comment: @JonasH I think the reason is: This is supposed to be a **step-by-step visualization animation** of how QuickSort works internally ... so using any method which does already actually sort the items will be not of much use ^^

Comment: That exactly what I'm trying to do. It's just a portoflio project where items are sorted on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just using `StartCoroutine` you are running the subsequent Coroutines as new **parallel** routines.

If you want to actually wait until these recursive routines are **finished** before running the next one then you have to `yield` them like e.g.

```
// This already "runs" this IEnumerator and at the same time waits until it is done
yield return QuickSort(cubes, 0, pivotIndex - 1);
yield return QuickSort(cubes, pivotIndex + 1, cubes.Length - 1);
```

*you also don't need the `StartCoroutine` then at all. This would only be required if you would want to be able to use `StopCoroutine` on the individual started routines.*

Honestly personally I wouldn't mix too much between LeanTween and coroutines, though ;)

Comment: Omg, that was so simple haha! It's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: btw, regarding LeanTween and courutines working together, I already know what you mean. Few of "yield return new WaitForSeconds(time that LeanTween is doing it's job) solved problem, but I had a headache because of that too haha!

The reason why I didn't resign on LeanTween is because Quick sort is just one of few other sorting alghoritms that I have already done.

Comment: I can't vote up your answer cause I don't have enough reputation points. Sorry..

Comment: @RafałGruba you can mark the answer as accepted via the checkmark `✓` ;)